# Can the words 'basic' and 'basically' be pronounced with [z] instead of [s]?

Tags: pronunciation, consonants

In dictionaries, I have only found the version with [s] but I heard Ryan Stiles on *Whose Line Is It Anyway?* pronounce "basically" with a [z].

Comment: When have you heard it pronounced with [z]? What made you ask this question?

Comment: I've only ever heard it with /s/, but there are English dialects where some intervocalic /s/'s change to /z/. The American Midlands pronunciation of the word _greasy_, for instance, uses a /z/ instead of an /s/.

Comment: I heard pronouncing basic /bei'zik/ in the song below:
https://youtu.be/f78LzJEY03Q looked up this word in the dictionary and I find that s is pronounced as /s/.but in the song above the singer pronounced it like this :/bei'zik/.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pronunciation of 'has' (/z/ or /s/) before /tʃ/](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/527553/pronunciation-of-has-z-or-s-before-t%ca%83)

Comment: @FilipeAraujo: Because that's just how English works. Don't expect any kind of consistency.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the misunderstanding seems to be based on a single occurrence.

Answer (score 7):

No, "basic" and "basically" should always be pronounced with [s].

Ryan Stiles' usage on *Whose Line Is It Anyway?* was purely for comedic effect and, if I remember correctly, is part of his impression of Carol Channing and involves turning a great number of [s] sounds into [z] sounds. (I was unable to find the exact clip.)

Comment: @WineBuG: Lawler's point is just that some dialects have special pronunciations; it just comes with the accent. You can find more details on the Midland American accent on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midland_American_English) but they don't explicitly mention the [s]/[z] changes. Finding audio examples could be a bit difficult but I'll poke around later today and see what I can find.

Answer (score 1):

Basal  can be pronounced with S and Z but not basic

Basal (S)   relating to , forming or concerning a Base.

Basal (Z)   located near the stem of a plant (Botany)