# Pronunciation of 'has' (/z/ or /s/) before /tʃ/

Tags: pronunciation, pronunciation-vs-spelling, sounds

When **'s'** comes before a **voiced consonant**, it's usually pronounced as /z/.

Example: He ha**s b**een banned. (here 's' is pronounced as /z/ because the following consonant is voiced.)

On the other hand, when it precedes a **voiceless consonant**, it's usually pronounced as /s/.

Example: She ha**s t**o go home, (here the 's' of 'has' is usually pronounced as /s/ because the following consonant is voiceless.)

**Question:**
How to pronounce 's' when it precedes **/tʃ/**? Will it be pronounced as /z/ or /s/?

**For example:**

- He ha**s ch**anged his clothes.

Comment: The 's' is voiced before 'ch'.

Comment: Voicing of sibilants varies widely. It is certainly not uniform among speakers, nor among phonological contexts (except when required in idioms like _has to_). More important than abstract imaginary rules is the fact that the extremely common auxiliary verbs _is_ and _has_ are virtually **always** contracted with their subjects, especially if they're pronouns. And then they're frozen, like all contractions. So the tendency is to voice those sibilants, in any environment. Before another sibilant, however, they would merge and be lost.

Comment: The ch changes very slightly when speaking fast, too - tongue hits slightly closer to the teeth than a ch on its own.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This is wrong, at least in the U.S.

In the U.S., the pronunciation of *has* is /hæz/, except when it appears in the construction *has to*, when it is pronounced /hæs/. *He has two leaves*: /z/. *He has to leave*: /s/. See the [Merriam-Webster Dictionary](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/have).

(The /s/ and /z/ often change their degree of voicing somewhat depending on whether a voiced or non-voiced consonant follows, but this is the case for all /s/'s and /z/'s at the end of a word in the English language, and is not related to the difference between *has two* and *has to*. Native English speakers lengthen vowels before a voiced consonant, so for some speakers, the difference between *has to* and *has two* could be mainly in the length of the /æ/.)

As mentioned in the comments, in the U.K., the dictionaries say that the pronunciations are /hæz/ and /hæv/, and don't give exceptions before *to*. But I wouldn't be surprised if some British speakers used the same rules as Americans do.

Comment: The parenthetical comment is in my answer: (The /s/ and /z/ often change their degree of voicing somewhat depending on whether a voiced or non-voiced consonant follows, but this is the case for all /s/'s and /z/'s at the end of a word in the English language, and is not related to the difference between has two and has to.) We pronounce *has two* with less voicing than *has one*, but with a lot more voicing than *has to*. And we perceive the phoneme in *has two* as a /z/, even though speakers of some foreign languages may perceive it as more like an /s/.

Comment: In "has to", I only pronounce "has" as /hæs/ in fast speech. In careful speech it becomes /hæz/ again. I'm sure this is the same for other native speakers.

Comment: @CJDennis: I'm a native speaker, and I'm pretty sure I say it as /hæs/ even in careful speech. But if by "other native speakers" you just mean "*some* other native speakers", then sure, you're probably not a weird unprecedented anomaly. :-)

Comment: Native speaker here, and I pronounce it /hæz/ in every environment, including in "has to".

Comment: C.f. "have to" /hæf tu/ vs. "have two" /hæv tu/. Also FWIW I'm also a native speaker (Maritimer) and I always devoice "has" and "have" before "to". [Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/have_to) says there's a divide between UK and US English.

Comment: Another Brit here: both are often devoiced, not consistently, and often only partially. In my experience more common, or at least noticeable, with "have"‌. Often stems from emphasis placed on the word as much as any kind of pronunciation rule (*Why are you doing that? Because I have to.*). There's also the fact that the airflow has to stop when you hit the 't' anyway, so the 'z' changes to 's' *halfway through*.